# Is It Possible (or Inadvisable) to Run Apache Without Apachectl?

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm using Apache inside a Docker container, and want to attach the process to the container (preventing forking). However, all the documentation says to run using apachectl, which immediately exits and runs apache under the hood. Is there a clean way to run apache directly?

I've tried the following, but it fails:

```
$ source /etc/apache2/envvars
$ /usr/sbin/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/sites-available/rails.conf
AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need apachectl. You do need to include apache2.conf or some alternative.

```
# source /etc/apache2/envvars
# apache2 -f /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

If you want to run it in the foreground

```
# apache2 -f /etc/apache2/apache2.conf -DFOREGROUND
```